# Add internet explorer 7 to Windows XP Mode in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

Does anybody know if it is possible to to add Internet explorer to run as a windows XP mode application under windows 7?  I have one web application that I need to use for work that only works in IE7 or earlier (does not work in IE 8's compatibility mode either).

Currently I have been going into the windows XP virtual machine and running IE7 right from there, but I am trying to figure out how to add it as a shortcut under Windows XP Mode Applications like the other software i have installed on the XP virtual machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last I checked, for  the shortcut to show up in the Windows 7 menu it needs to be in the XP VMs "All Users" Program group and the VM needs to be running. At least that's what I keep reading. I haven't had a chance to play with it further... :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling IE8 for XP Mode to let you [install IE7](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9AE91EBE-3385-447C-8A30-081805B2F90B&displaylang=en)?

Comment: XP mode installs IE6 by default.  I did upgrade it to IE7 to see if that would add the shortcut (it didn't). I mooling for a way to make the program which is allready installed on the XP vm show up as a shortcut under Windows XP mode Applications